# Prometheus configuration and deployment in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, prometheus, configmap

I have an IaaC project that use Terraform and Helm charts to deploy Prometheus (along with Grafana, Kubernetes and the platform app). I do have Kubernetes metrics on Prometheus. However, I realize that the configuration on deployed Prometheus doesn't really come from the Prometheus config file in the project. I am not sure if it's the problem with configMap or other configuration. Here are the files concerned in the project:

`/terraform/kubernetes/files/prometheus_config_map.yaml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component]
    action: replace
    target_label: job
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

`/terraform/kubernetes/prometheus.tf`

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "prometheus" {
  metadata {
    name = "prometheus"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map" "prometheus_config" {
  metadata {
    name      = "prometheus-config"
    namespace = "prometheus"
  }

  data = {
    "prometheus.yml" = file("${path.module}/files/prometheus_config_map.yaml")
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace.prometheus
  ]
}

# Values documentation: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/values.yaml
resource "helm_release" "prometheus" {
  name        = "prometheus"
  repository  = local.helm_repositories.bitnami
  chart       = "kube-prometheus"
  version     = "3.4.0"
  namespace   = "prometheus"
  atomic      = true
  max_history = 5

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/helm_values/security.yaml.tpl"),
    file("${path.module}/helm_values/prometheus.yaml")
  ]

  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_config_map.prometheus_config
  ]
}
```

`/terraform/kubernetes/helm_values/prometheus.yaml`

```
prometheus:
  podMetadata:
    annotations:
      container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/prometheus-operator: runtime/default
      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default

nodeAffinityPreset:
  ## Node affinity type
  ## Allowed values: soft, hard
  ##
  type: "hard"
  ## Node label key to match
  ## E.g.
  ## key: "kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name"
  ##
  key: "cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool"
  ## Node label values to match
  ## E.g.
  ## values:
  ##   - e2e-az1
  ##   - e2e-az2
  ##
  values: [
    "project-primary-pool"
  ]

prometheus:  
  configMaps:
    - prometheus-config
```

In this file `/terraform/kubernetes/helm_values/prometheus.yaml`, I tried to remove the last `prometheus:` and moved `configMaps:` to the root as per this [documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/values.yaml) but it broke the Prometheus configuration.
As you can see in the file `/terraform/kubernetes/files/prometheus_config_map.yaml`, the `scrape_interval` is `15s` but when I check on Prometheus UI config, all of the scrape_interval is 30s, therefore, for sure the configuration of deployed Prometheus doesn't come from this file. Therefore, I have no way to change the configuration such as scrape_interval

[image: promConfig1]

I also notice in this [documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/values.yaml) that I am missing many configuration in the file `/terraform/kubernetes/helm_values/prometheus.yaml` but I am not certain of what to add. Could you please let me know how I can resolve this? Thank you in advance.

[image: promCONFIGmount]

Answer (score 1):

in values.yaml if you check the line : 577

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/values.yaml

there is an option to mount the config map to the deployment.

> ### ConfigMaps that should be mounted into the Prometheus Pods
>
> configMaps: []

you can set the config map to the deployment and change the time of interval.

if it's not using the config map values it must be using the default config from volume or directly you can go inside the POD and check that once also to verify.

Comment: Thank you @Harsh Manvar for your reply. I did check the deployment after and the Mount seems to be empty, as its `None` [PromConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9sNE.png) this is not what we expect right? However, I do have configMap section if you see my file above, can you suggest me what I missed here?

Comment: @shuti check if confimap getting appiled to the deployment of prom or not, as scrape config is stored inside the configmap so or else you should try adding or updating default scrape config file in volume to verify which file is getting load.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use curl to do it. The script is in below:

```
#get the image_artifacts and change to url format

Image_artifacts=$(printf ${Image#*/}|jq -sRr '@uri'|sed 's|%2F|%252F|g') 

curl -u $Harbor_User:$Harbor_Passwd -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://${Harbor_Address}/api/v2.0/projects/$Project/repositories/${Image_artifacts}/artifacts?page_size=100"|jq '.[]|select (.pull_time>"2023-02-06")'|jq '.tags[].name'
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.